# HLSL How to flip geometry horizontally

Tags: shaders, hlsl, geometry, vertex-shader

I want to flip my asymmetric 3d model horizontally in the vertex shader alongside an arbitrary plane parallel to the YZ plane. This should switch everything for the model from the left hand side to the right hand side (like flipping it in Photoshop). Doing it in pixel shader would be a huge computational cost (extra RT, more fullscreen samples...), so it must be done in the vertex shader.
Once more: this is NOT reflection, i need to flip THE WHOLE MODEL.

I thought I could simply do the following:

1. Turn off culling.
2. Run the following code in the vertex shader:

   ```
   input.Position = mul(input.Position, World);

   // World[3][0] holds x value of the model's pivot in the World.
   if (input.Position.x <= World[3][0])
       input.Position.x += World[3][0] - input.Position.x;
   else
       input.Position.x -= input.Position.x - World[3][0];

   ...
   ```

The model is never drawn. Where am I wrong? I presume that messes up the index buffer. Can something be done about it?

P.S. it's INSANELY HARD to format code here.

Thanks to Panda I found my problem. SOLUTION:

```
// Do thins before anything else in the vertex shader.
Position.x *= -1;   // To invert alongside the object's YZ plane.
```

Comment: You never flip geomatry. thats impossible with out geomatry shader. and pretty pointless. do the full model in your modeling tool instead-

Comment: There IS a point for us. We will need to add a lot more animations if we don't flip it. Could you please explain WHY it is impossible?

Comment: Befor hand, do you have a Half object and just want to flip it to the otherside? or do you have a Whole object and just want to invert it? your question was quite diffuse.

Comment: Nope I want to flip the whole object, this is not reflection.

Comment: You do know that both `input.Position.x += World[3][0] - input.Position.x;` and `input.Position.x -= input.Position.x - World[3][0];` are equivalent to `input.Position.x = World[3][0];`, right? You're setting the X coordinates of all vertices to the same value...

Comment: that did not at all answer my question. but if you want to flip it, just invert your scaleing matrix.

Comment: Damn u r right, I'm terrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you use a transformation matrix and pass it into the shader? Flipping can be done with a negative scale value. But maybe  misunderstood you, Iam not sure.

Comment: I won't try it as I found my own way (it should be the same really but in the shader). Good thing it flips the TexCoords as well. Check the main question for solution.